# How to disable auto scroll in the horizontal scroll bar

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a tree view where i want to enable auto scroll for vertical scroll bar but want that feature to be disabled for horizontal scroll bar.

i could only find autoscroll option for this but it enables and disables both the scroll bars simultaneously.

Tree view is derived from QAbstractItemModel.

Comment: Technically, there is no question, although the button clearly says: _Ask Question_. More importantly though, there is a lack of a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @scopchanov please check this out https://forum.qt.io/topic/116405/how-to-disable-auto-scroll-for-horizontal-bar

Comment: i feel this is a valid question and someone has also answered it.

Comment: @scopchanov this is something i could not find in the qt documents , so asking some expert person on the qt for the same.

Comment: It is not about the topic, it is about the way it has been asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them separately like this:

```
my_treeview->horizontalScrollbar()
```

Comment: This does not even attempt to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can change de policy of both scrollbars, in this case

```
my_treeview->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

Comment: i dont want to turn the horizontal bar off but i want to turn the autoscroll feature in the horizontal bar.